# Hours to working days

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

Where I work I don't get paid overtime, but I accrue holiday days for the overtime I work. I have the following spreadsheet which calculates how much overtime I've done and totals it in `D15`.

Now I want to calculate how many days this is, based on 8 hours per day. In `D16`, I've done `=D15/8` and formatted it as `h.mm \d\a\y\s`, but this shows as `2.26 days` instead of `2.4375 days`.

What is the correct formula to use in `D16`?

[image]

Comment: What are your formulae in D3-13 and then in D15?

Comment: **D3-D13:** `=(B1-IF(B3="",B1,B3))+(IF(C3="", C1, C3)-C1)` (replace 3 with row number) **D15:** `=SUM(D3:D14)`. It's pretty much irrelevant though, because you can enter anything in a test cell and format it as `hh:mm` to get a 'mock' `D15` cell.

Comment: You may find this link useful http://www.cpearson.com/excel/overtime.htm It also has some Additional Resources: towards the bottom.

Comment: @pnuts The `B$1` trick will be perfect, it was really bugging me that I couldn't copy the formula down. About the 2nd issue, I'm not in the office at the moment, but do you care to tell me what happens? Thanks!

Comment: @pnuts Ah, if the total time (`D15`) goes over 24 hours, it resets to 0. Nasty bug! How can I fix this? Thanks for the `B$1` trick though, that worked perfectly!

Comment: @pnuts I don't want it to be able to have a different start and end time every day. It should be the same every day. I managed to get it to sum more than 24 hours by changing `D15`'s format to `[h]:mm`, but the conversion to days (`D16`) still rolls over to 0. Still looking for a solution to that...

Comment: @pnuts Ok - answer is: `=((DAY(D20)*24)+HOUR(D20)+(MINUTE(D20)/60))/8` in `D16` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note to reader:* this question led to multiple solutions some of which were discussed in the comments. Here is a summary of the solution found.

---

**First solution**

```
=(HOUR(D15)+MINUTE(D15)/60)/8
```

**Explanation**

Dates and time in Excel are **stored as serial numbers**, so `19:30` is actually `0.8125`.
So, if you divide it by `8`, you will get `0.1015625`.
This latter value is worth `2.26 days`

---

**OP's version** (thanks to Danny Becket (OP)) - see the comments below.
This solution now handles hours > 24.

```
=((DAY(D20)*24)+HOUR(D20)+(MINUTE(D20)/60))/8
```

or better (credits to [Barry Houdini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124287/barry-houdini)):

```
=((INT(D20)*24)+HOUR(D20)+(MINUTE(D20)/60))/8
```

The former formula has a limitation for large values, perhaps not relevant here but if `D20` is 800:00 then you get the wrong answer (7 days rather than 100 days). This is probably because `DAY` function is giving you calendar day which will "reset" at 31, best to use `INT` in place of `DAY`.

---

**Another easily understandable version**

Divide by the length of the day as a time value:

```
=D15/"8:00"
```

More easily changed if length of workday changes

Comment: Probably should be `HOUR(D15)` for an english-version Excel.

Comment: Sorry, thanks @HansKesting for the correction. I often get issues when answering for formulas on Stackovervlow because my Excel is not in english.

Comment: Perfect! I formatted it as `0.00 \d\a\y\s` and it works great; thanks @JMax!

Comment: @pnuts: I don't understand why you think it is not correct, I've tested it on my version with the very same values and it worked well. Plus, the OP accepted my answer so it seems like it works for him too. I don't see what's the point in downvoting in such situations but whatever, that's not important :)

Comment: @JMax @pnuts Edited slightly and now it copes with total times of >24 hours: `=((DAY(D20)*24)+HOUR(D20)+(MINUTE(D20)/60))/8` :)

Comment: @DannyBeckett: thanks. I've edited the answer so that it reflets the final solution

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, yes, `D20` should read `D16`. I can't see a shift ever spanning midnight, but if it does, I'm more than happy to write finish at 11:59 and start at 00:00 on a new row.

Comment: @pnuts For any regular hours there is no row ;)

Comment: Didn't pnuts suggest this in comments somewhere else (?), but why not =D15*3, or more understandable (and more easily changed if length of workday changes), divide by the length of the day as a time value, i.e. =D15/"8:00" - in both cases that would give you the same result as the accepted answer

Comment: @barryhoudini: do you plan to post this as an answer so that we could upvote it? Or either feel free to edit my post to append your solution.

Comment: I didn't want to "steal" what was essentially pnuts' suggestion.....Note that =((DAY(D20)*24)+HOUR(D20)+(MINUTE(D20)/60))/8 also has a limitation for large values, perhaps not relevant here but if D20 is 800:00 then you get the wrong answer (7 days rather than 100 days). This is because DAY function is giving you calendar day which will "reset" at 31, best to use INT in place of DAY, I think

Comment: @barryhoudini: I eventually made this answer community wiki because many of you have contributed to it and I tried to format it in a readable way. Feel free to edit and improve if you think this is necessary

Answer (score 2):

Enter:

in `B3`   **8:3**
in `C3`   **16:3**
in `D3`   `=IF(B3<C3,C3-B3-1/3,2/3-B3+C3)`

Select `B3:D3`, format as `hh:mm` and copy down as far as required.

Sum `ColumnD` and append `*3` to the formula, but format as Number.

Add data by overwriting cells in `ColumnB` and/or `ColumnC` as required (defaults do not add to total).

- Copes with overtime up to next regular start time (ie including past midnight, new serial number). `1/3` because standard working day is 8 hours (24 hours is unity for date serial counter). `B3` and `C3` could be hard coded but (i) there is no need and (ii) allows more flexibility. If to readily identify non standard start/finish could use conditional formatting.
- Does not address weekend overtime but could easily be adapted to do so (eg add column, flag weekend day with 8 in that extra column then add that 8 [1/3] to the finish time).

Comment: Interesting but not very easy to read. +1 for the 24 hours issue solving

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that D15 has a number format of [h]:mm 
then have D16 as =sum(D15/"8:00") should work fine
thats what i have tracking my annual leave, I work 37h pw with a leave day being classed as 7h24m or a half day of leave as "3:42"

I have leave taken as a cumulative figure assigned as [h]:mm in cell K2 of my spreadsheet
then I have K3=SUM(K2/"7:24") for days taken formatted as a general number

you may also need to change the date datum in excel to the 1904 date system http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182247/en-gb
to get this to work (only a problem if you have negative time as I do when calculating flex hours)